# Как получить с контроллера на js json объект?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc

Как правильно получить *JSON*-объект с контроллера во *вьюшку*? точнее, на скрипт, чтобы дальше с ним работать.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно перевести некий объект в JSON во вьюхе и сразу использовать при загрузке страницы то я рекомендую использовать nuget пакет Newtonsoft.JSON
(Отпадает необходимость в доп. хелпере)

- для MVC:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var lookups = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.lookups));
  </script>
  ```
- для WebForms:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var lookups = parseJSON('<%= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyServices.GetLookups()) %>');
  </script>
  ```

Если же необходимо возвращать Json из Web API то в методе WebApiConfig.Register() должна присутствовать команда

```
configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

Comment: спасибо большое очень помог Ваш ответ

Comment: @SamatYeshernkulov тогда, думаю, стоит отметить мой ответ как верный.

Answer (score 0):

Если надо отрендерить модель как часть скрипта на странице, то это можно сделать при помощи примерно такого хелпера:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString ToJsonString(this HtmlHelper helper, object data)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml
        };

        string json;
        var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
            json = writer.ToString();
        }

        return helper.Raw(json);
    }
}
```

и во вьюшке:

```
<script>
    var something = @Html.ToJsonString(Model);
</script>
```

Если надо просто загрузить JSON с сервера со стороны бразуера, то нужно сделать отдельный Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    return Json(new SomeModel() { Property1 = 42, Property2 = "test" });
}
```

и вызвать его с клиентской стороны (например, через jQuery):

```
$.post('@Url.Action("SomeAction")', function (data)
{
    // в data придет результат от сервера
    console.log(data);
})
```